# Como criar um ponteiro para guardar o endereço de uma raiz de árvore binário e depois usar este endereço para chamar a raiz?

Tags: c, ponteiro, árvore-binária, árvores-de-expressão

Iai galera, to com um problema no meu codigo aparentemente simples de resolver, mas ainda me confundo com ponteiros.

O código é para inserir cada algarismo e operador de uma expressão toda parenteseada numa árvore binária. A lógica é, ao encontrar um "(", preencho a raiz com "#" e guardo o endereço desta raiz numa pilha para depois ser usado e chamar essa raiz de novo e preencher com o operador que será encontrado.

Ex: Recebe a expressão (2+3). A raiz será "#", então chama a função para a esquerda e preenche com "2" e chama a função de novo. Ao encontrar "+", chama a função de acessar o topo da pilha e pegar o endereço guardado pelo ponteiro e chamar a raiz que está com "#" e substituir com "+". Então chama a função de inserir de novo apontando para a direito a partir desta raiz e preenche com "3".

Fiz alguns testes de impressão e acredito q as outras funções funcionam corretamente. Após terminada a função de inserir, coloco pra imprimir a raiz e sai "+", porém não há subárvores pois é a única coisa q imprime.

```
Arvore *Inserir(Arvore *raiz, char expressao[], int j, Pilha *PILHA){

char k = '#'; 

if(expressao[j] == '('){
    if(raiz == NULL){
        raiz = Criar_Raiz(k);
    }
    Arvore *ponteiro = (Arvore*)malloc(sizeof(Arvore));
    ponteiro = raiz; // ponteiro recebe o endereço da raiz marcada com "#"
    Inserir_Pilha(PILHA, ponteiro); //insere o ponteiro com o endereço na pilha

    j++; 
    Inserir(raiz -> esquerda, expressao, j, PILHA);} 
else if((expressao[j] == '+') || (expressao[j] == '-') || (expressao[j] == '*') || (expressao[j] == '/')){

    Pilha *TOPO = Acessa_Topo_Pilha(PILHA); 

    raiz = TOPO -> endereco; // pega o endereço (raiz) armazenado no topo da pilha que indica o endereço da raiz a ser usada
    raiz -> item = expressao[j]; 

    j++; 
    Inserir(raiz -> direita, expressao, j, PILHA);} 
else if(expressao[j] == ')'){ 
    Retirar_Pilha(PILHA);
    if (Vazia(PILHA))
         j = 0;
    else{
        j++;
        Inserir(raiz, expressao, j, PILHA);
    }
}
else{ // se for algarismo
    if(raiz == NULL)
        raiz = Criar_Raiz(expressao[j]);

    j++; 
    Inserir(raiz, expressao, j, PILHA);
}
return raiz;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVIDO]

Foram necessárias mudanças bem simples que não prestei atenção antes, e o ponteiro tava fazendo td certo. O código da função Inserir que foi postado foi o único modificado.

```
Arvore *Inserir(Arvore *raiz, char expressao[], int j, Pilha *PILHA){ // Função de inserir na árvore    

Arvore *ponteiro = (Arvore*)malloc(sizeof(Arvore)); // mudança feita aqui
char k = '#';

if(expressao[j] == '('){ 
    if(raiz == NULL) // verifica se a raiz é nula
        raiz = Criar_Raiz(k);


    ponteiro = raiz; // ponteiro recebe o endereço da raiz marcada com "#"
    Inserir_Pilha(PILHA, ponteiro); //insere o ponteiro com o endereço na pilha
    j++;
    raiz -> esquerda = Inserir(raiz -> esquerda, expressao, j, PILHA);} //mudança feita aqui

else if((expressao[j] == '+') || (expressao[j] == '-') || (expressao[j] == '*') || (expressao[j] == '/')){ // quando encontra um operador na expressão
    Pilha *TOPO = Acessa_Topo_Pilha(PILHA);
    raiz = TOPO -> endereco;
    raiz -> item = expressao[j];
    j++; 
    raiz -> direita = Inserir(raiz -> direita, expressao, j, PILHA);} //mudança feita aqui

else if(expressao[j] == ')'){
    Retirar_Pilha(PILHA);
    if (Vazia(PILHA))
         j = 0;colocada na árvore. sai da função
    else{ // se não está vazia
        j++; //
        Inserir(raiz, expressao, j, PILHA);
    }
}

else{ // se for algarismo
    if(raiz == NULL)
        raiz = Criar_Raiz(expressao[j]); 
    j++; 
    Inserir(ponteiro, expressao, j, PILHA); // mudança feita aqui
}
return raiz;
}
```